# Using $\epsilon$-$N$ definition of limit prove that: if $\lim x_{n} = 1$, then $\lim |5x_n - 3| = |5-3| = 2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

Here is the problem:

Using the $ \epsilon$-$N $ definition of limit. Prove that if $ lim \space x_{n} = 1 $, then $ lim \space|5x_{n} - 3| = |5-3| = 2$

We have been given

$$
\tag{1}\forall \space \epsilon >0 \space \exists \space N , \space \forall \space n > N \space |x_{n}-1| < \epsilon 
$$

We wish to show that some M exists, such that

$$
\tag{2}\forall \space \epsilon > 0 \space \exists \space M, \space \forall \space n > M \space ||5x_{n}-3|-2|<\epsilon
$$

Due to the nested inequality, I examine two cases:

When $x \ge \frac{3}{5}; |5x_{n} - 3 | = 5x_{n} - 3$

Using the reverse triangle inequality we get $ |5x_{n} - 3 | - |2| \le |5x_{n} - 5| = 5|x_{n}-1| $. Can I then pick a value? Say $\epsilon ', \epsilon ' > 0, \space where \space \epsilon ' =5\epsilon$, so that I can then say - $ |5x_{n} - 3 | - |2| \le 5 |x_{n} - 1| < \epsilon ' \implies |5x_{n} - 3 | - |2| \le |x_{n} - 1 | < \frac{5\epsilon}{5} = \epsilon$

Thus, giving me the inequality I need to show that $ ||5x_{n} - 3| - 2| < \epsilon $ (I'm taking liberty with the $\le$ here).

I would then use a similar approach to show the second case when $x < \frac{3}{5}$

Comment: Hi, just a small note on formatting. You can also use MathJax in your question title, because you haven't reached your character limit.

Comment: You don't have to worry about the absolute values meas,  There  is a $K$ so that $n > K$ implies $|x_n - 1| < \frac 15$.  So if $n > K$ than $\frac 45 < x_n < \frac 6$ and $1 < 5x_n -3 < 3$.  So if we assume $M\ge K$ then $5x_n -3 > 0$ so $|5x_n -3| = 5x_n -3$

Comment: "I would then use a similar approach to show the second case when  $x < \frac 35$.  No.  You would completely *ignore* when $x_n < \frac 35$ because you can always find a $N$ where $n> N$ implies $x_n$ is too close to $1$ to be less than $\frac 35$.

Comment: @fleablood for your first comment. Because we are given $|x_{n} -1| < \epsilon$, so $|x_{n}-1| < \frac{\epsilon}{5}$. Regrettably, I don’t see where the $\frac{1}{5}$ came from. Could you explain a bit more? Totally agree with second comment.

Comment: I picked the $\frac 15$ out of my ass.  I *know* that $x_n \to 1$ so we could always find a $K$ large enough that for $n > K$ we'd have $5x_n -3 > 0$.  I picked $\frac 15$ because that would make $x_n > \frac 45$ and $5x_n > 4$ and $5x_n -3 > 4-3 =1> 0$.

Comment: The thing about limits is we are always assuming we can get as close to our goal as we wish.  If we we have a pesky decimal point or absolute value anything else giving ourselves grief, well, then we just pick values that get beyond that.  Where is I get $\frac 15$? I picked it because it was small enough.  $\frac 1{5000000000}$ is even *smaller* and we could have picked that.  That's really small enough.

Answer (score 1):

You are making it too hard on yourself.

If $\epsilon =\frac 25$ then there is a $K$ so that $n > K$ will imply $|x_n - 1| < \frac 25$.  That means if $n > K$ then $x_n > \frac 35$.

So just assume $M \ge K$ and we will *always* have $n> M\implies 5x_n - 3 > 0$ and we can completely *ignore* worrying about $x_n \le \frac 35$.

......

Now  if we want $||5x_n - 3| - 2| < \epsilon$ and we assume $n$ is at least as high as the $K$ above, we want $|5x_n - 5| < \epsilon$.

But $|5x_n - 5| < \epsilon \iff |x_n - 1| < \frac 15 \epsilon$.

Now we know there is an $L$ so that if $n > L$ then $|x_n-1| < \frac 15\epsilon$.

So if we let $M = \max(K,L)$ there $K$ is so that $n > K\implies |x_n-1| < \frac 25$ and $L$ is such that $|x_n -1| < \frac 15 \epsilon$ then if

$n > M\ge K$ then we have $|x_n-1| < \frac 25$ so $x_n > \frac 35$ and $5x_n -3 > 0$ and $|5x_n -3| =5x_n -3$.

And if $n > M \ge L$ then we have $||5x_n -3| - 2| = |5x_n-5| > 5\times \frac 15 \epsilon = \epsilon$.

And that's it.  That's all.

Comment: Just for my own benefit here - we pick an $M = max(K,L)$ will give us an index that satisfies the inequality regardless of which one is larger. Shown above by your work manipulating the absolute value and inequalities. Finally we show that for our chosen index $M$ we arrive at our final inequality $||5x_{n} -3|-2| < \epsilon$. Which finishes the proof because this verifies that the limit is equal to 2, which is equal to $|5-3|$. Am I reading this correct?